# Methods to solve $x^2+(x')^2=1$ and similar nonlinear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

How do I solve the following:

$x^2 + \left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 = 1$

Please refer me to an online resource that has worked examples that I can work through to practice.

I have the answer : $ x = \cos{t} $

I need to understand how to get to the answer.

Comment: You need to add an initial condition as you can obtain $x=\sin(t)$ as a valid solution also - but it depends if we have $x(0) =0$ or $x(0) = 1$ for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equations of the type $f(x,x')=0$ or, in general, $f(t,x,x')=0$ are called *implicit differential equations*. The major technique is to solve the nonlinear algebraic equation first and try to get one or several explicit expressions for $x'$ e.g. of the type $x'=\phi(x)$, resp. $x'=\phi(t,x)$. In some cases, it is convenient to take a parametric solution to $f(x,x')=0$ as $x=g_1(\theta)$, $x'=g_1(\theta)$. For example, to solve your equation one can parameterise $(x,x')$, which is a point on the unit circle, by $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ as
$$
\begin{cases}
x(t)=\sin\theta(t),\\
x'(t)=\cos\theta(t).
\end{cases}
$$
Then differentiating the first one we get $x'=\theta'(t)\cos\theta(t)$, hence, $\theta'=1$, thus, $\theta(t)=t+c$, or $\cos\theta(t)=0$, thus, $\theta(t)=\pi/2+\pi k$ (the constant solution).

Note that there is no uniqueness of solution at $x=\pm 1$, so each time the trajectory passes $x=\pm 1$ one can switch to another solution, for example, one can come to $x=1$ along $\sin(t+c)$, then switch to the constant solution $x=1$ for while, and then move along another $\sin(t+c)$.

You can find some information [here](http://www.efunda.com/math/ode/ode1_implicit.cfm) and [here](https://www.math24.net/implicit-differential-equations/) and perhaps much more to google (like [here](https://books.google.se/books?id=2jvaBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA46&ots=JQUbPvAAM6&dq=implicit%20first%20order%20differential%20equation&hl=sv&pg=PA46#v=onepage&q&f=false))

Answer (score 3):

$x^2 + (\frac{dx}{dt})^2 = 1 \Leftrightarrow \frac{dx}{dt} = \sqrt{1-x^2} $ or $\frac{dx}{dt} = -\sqrt{1-x^2} $

Now you have :

$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = \int dt$ or $ \int -\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = \int dt $

Which yield you the solutions : $\arcsin(x) = t+c$ or  $-\arcsin(x) = t+c$

Which means : $x(t) = -\sin(t+c_1)$ or $x(t) = \sin(t+c_1)$

Now, depending on your initial conditions, you will be leaded to the answer you mentioned : $x(t) = \cos t$

Comment: Now, for similar equations, try googling for non-linear differential equations to find textbooks. Internet is always your friend and on such well-known exercises, you can find countless solutions.

Comment: Boyce - Di Prima is also a really good and wide book I've used during my Differential semesters, it has tons of stuff, maybe it has such examples as well (can't remember clearly).

Comment: The constant function $x(t)=1$ satisfies the DE, but it is not $\sin(t+c)$ for any $c$.

Answer (score -2):

$$x^2 + (\frac{dx}{dt})^2 = 1$$
$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = \sqrt{1-x^2}$$
$$\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = dt$$
$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = \int dt$$
$$ \arcsin(x)= t + c $$
$$ x(t) = \sin(t+c)$$

Comment: $\dot x=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ means that $\dot x\ge 0$, but $\sin(t+c)$ may have negative derivative.

Comment: what textbook or online site can I go to so that I can work through similar questions?

Comment: I don't see why this gives me such negative votes. Locally this doesn't matter much, and globally I can just use the solution with $\dot{x} = -\sqrt{...} $

Comment: It is hard to say. Anonymous downvoting here seems to be quite alogical sometimes. By the way, you also missed the constant solutions $x=\pm 1$ when divided by $\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

Comment: I agree with you about that.